# How to remove duplicate comma separate strings using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file like this: (named test2.csv)

```
lastname,firstname,83494989,1997-05-20,2015-05-07 15:30:43,Sentence Skills 104,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 38,Elementary Algebra 38,Sentence Skills 104,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 38,Elementary Algebra 38,
```

I want to remove the duplicate entries

The closest I have got is the following awk command

```
awk '{a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print RS i}' RS="," test2.csv
```

it works but causes new problems, it take the values out of order and puts them in rows like this:

```
,Elementary Algebra 38
,2015-05-07 15:30:43
,Sentence Skills 104
,FirstName
,LastName
,1997-05-20
,83494989
```

I need to keep the order they are in and keep them in one line ( I can fix the row issue, but don't know how to fix the order issue)

**Update with Solution:**

The answer from anubhava worked great, I added a question about removing the time from the date and Ed Morton helped out with that, here is the full query

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} {sub(/ ..:..:..$/,"")} !seen[$0]++' test2.csv
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just use this awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} !seen[$0]++' test2.csv
lastname,firstname,83494989,1997-05-20,2015-05-07 15:30:43,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 38,
```

Comment: awesome, super clean. i looked for other way to do it but they looked way over complicated.

Comment: now i need to figure out how to remove the 24 hour time from one date. been attempting with regular expression and sed, but cant seem to get it to work

Comment: @moore1emu if youre using awk you do not need/want sed or grep or anything else since awk can internally do anything useful that the other tools can do. You're just going to want something like `{sub(/ ..:..:..$/,"")}` before the `!seen`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ed Morton, My AwkFu is weak and only just beginning, ill look into the sub query to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same

Change commas to new lines

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g'
```

Remove duplicate lines with sort -u

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | sort -u
```

And finally replace new lines back to commas

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' | sort -u | sed -e 's/\n/,/g'
```

Comment: You're missing the sed in the last part of the pipe series. Also, I couldn't get it to work, so I did a similar thing with tr command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
test='lastname,firstname,83494989,1997-05-20,2015-05-07 15:30:43,Sentence Skills 104,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 38,Elementary Algebra 38,Sentence Skills 104,Sentence Skills 104,Elementary Algebra 38,Elementary Algebra 38,'

echo $test |tr ',' '\n' | sort -u | grep . | tr '\n' ','
```

Explanation:

1. For readability, set the variable "test" to the comma delimited string.
2. Change the commas to newlines using tr command.
3. Remove duplicates using 'sort -u.'
4. Remove extra blank lines using 'grep.'
5. Change the newlines back to commas using the tr command.

This is probably not as elegant or as fast as other approaches, but it's easier for me to understand.