# remove duplicate numbers from comma separated list using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to find a single line command that can remove duplicate numbers from a comma separated list in Linux.

Using command: `grep ^[0-9] | cut -d '/' -f 1 | tr '\n' ',' | sed s/,$//`

I am trying to pipe this command into a command that also removes duplicate numbers.

Before list:

```
53,80,443,4577,4578,22222,41818,50123,58774,80,443,4567,4577,4578,33005,34367,80,139,443,445,515,631,1865,9100,80,99,443,3389,41800
```

After list:

```
53,80,443,4577,4578,22222,41818,50123,58774,4567,33005,34367,139,445,515,631,1865,9100,99,3389,41800
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Does this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742796/3776858) help you?

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
$ sed ':a;s/\(\(\b[0-9]\+\b\)\([0-9,]\+\)\?\),\2\b/\1/;ta' input_file
53,80,443,4577,4578,22222,41818,50123,58774,4567,33005,34367,139,445,515,631,1865,9100,99,3389,41800
```

Comment: `143,8080,22,22,80,143`

Comment: Maybe: `:a;s/\(\(\<[0-9]\+\>\)[0-9,]*\),\2\>/\1/;ta` (not portable)

Comment: @jhnc Good catch. Interestingly, the `awk` solution advised by Cyrus also has the same flaw.

Comment: still fails on `22,22`  :-)

Comment: neither `\b` nor `\<` / `\>` are portable but I think `\b` is slightly less (eg. bsd). `\+` is also not understood by busybox and bsd.

Comment: I think you should add your suggestion as an answer @jhnc

Answer (score 1):

suggesting `awk` script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","}{a[$0]=1}END{for(i in a)print i}' input.txt |sed 's|,$|\n|'
```

Comment: This won't retain the input order. You can use `awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=","} !a[$0]++'` instead. Also, this won't work if input line might also include newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If `perl` is okay:

```bash
perl -MList::Util=uniq -F, -lanE 'say join ",", uniq @F'
```

This uses builtin array processing feature `uniq` to retain only the first copy of duplicates. The `-F` option specifies the field separator.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/((^|,)([^,]+)(,.*)*),\3(,|$)/\1\5/;ta' file
```

Match from the beginning of the line or a comma, one or more non-comma characters, followed by zero or more strings beginning with a comma, followed by a duplicate of the second string in the match, followed by either a comma or the end of the line and if matched remove the duplicate preceded by a comma.

For each substitution repeat until failure to match.

Alternative:

```
sed -E ':a;s/\b(([^,]+)\b.*),\2\b/\1/;ta' file
```